# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing after expanding

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm making updates to an old landing page to make it responsive (full overhaul will be done later in the year), the issue I'm having is that once you click to expand navbar in mobile view (or resized window in desktop view) it doesn't collapse after clicking it again---however it works fine on the interior pages, it's pulling the same exact navbar through a reusable.

Here is the CSS for the landing page that I think is conflicting with the navbar's toggle. Testing being done on a samsung galaxy s5 running 7.1.

The page wrapper has all the necessary bootstrap css+js so I know its not that.

I did have to use a z-index on the navbar because the jumbotron was covering the toggle button, so after using that the toggle is now clickable, just won't close.

***Edit*** - sorry forgot to add link to the page: 
http://prairies-nwt.supportcbcf.com/site/PageNavigator/BABC_home.html

CSS:

```
@media (min-width:642px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
    background: url("http://convio.cancer.ca/BABC/2017/img/BABC_landingpage_banner.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
        background-size: contain;
        width: 100vw;
    height: 194px;
    position: relative;
    right: 2.2%;
    top: -40px;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }

    .closeGap {
    position: relative;
    right: 11% !important;
        margin-top: -70px;
    }

        .btn-default-width, .btn-default-width-winnipeg {
        width: 100vw;

        }

 }


@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    .closeGap {
        position: relative;
        right: 15.5% !important;
                margin-top: -150px;
    }

    .btn-default-width, .btn-default-width-winnipeg {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .addPad {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    }


}
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    .jumbotron {
    background: url("http://convio.cancer.ca/BABC/2017/img/BABC_landingpage_banner.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
        background-size: contain;
        width: 100vw;
    height: 194px;
    position: relative;
    right: 4.7%;
    top: -77px;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
 }

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .jumbotron {
    background: url("http://convio.cancer.ca/BABC/2017/img/BABC_landingpage_banner.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
        background-size: contain;
        width: 100vw;
    height: 194px;
    position: relative;
    right: 2.5%;
    top: -46px;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }

    .closeGap {
    position: relative;
    right: 11.5% !important;
        margin-top: -90px;
    }


 }
```

and here is the navbar:

```
<div class="nav navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.cbcf.org/battingagainstbc"><img src="../assets/images/ico_home.png" alt="home" /></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cbcf.org/central/ContactUs/Pages/default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.cbcf.org/central/AboutUsMain/Pages/default.aspx">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="DocServer/BABC-2017-Fundraising-Tips.pdf?docID=7676" target="_blank">Fundraising Ideas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

any suggestions would be hugely appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: inspect your web page and check console?

Comment: hi thanks for responding, I checked console and i only have a pagename not found error related to something else. I do get a warning that socialize.js without an apikey is unsupported but i have no idea what that is and I didn't insert it (could have been through the CMS)

Comment: "-however it works fine on the interior pages, it's pulling the same exact navbar through a reusable" that means something is surely conflicting, does your project is live? can you share link?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that forgot to add link to the page, I've edited it now, link is here http://prairies-nwt.supportcbcf.com/site/PageNavigator/BABC_home.html  taking a look at it some more, the jumbotron's div does overlap a bit onto the nav-menu once its expanded but isn't anywhere near toggle button...could that be what's affecting it?

Comment: @this.girish  Hi I figured out what the issue was, someone added another jquery script to the pagebuilder without notifying me (can't see it unless you go into the backend to check header field), and that was conflicting with the jquery in the page wrapper (where it should be), so all is working now. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I applied the patch but that did not provide an immediate solution. In my case this solved the problem:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap has display: none; there. The reason for this conflict is that bootstrap hides the menu and brings on it's menu for smaller screens.